# How to select value from dropdown without using submit

Tags: php, html, database, forms, laravel

I have two dropdowns: state and city. Both are in the same form. The goal is to somehow save the selection without clicking submit button so it could be used as a criteria to display selections of cities in the second dropdown. 
For example: When california is chosen in the first dropdown, second dropdwon displays all the cities in California.

Code:

```
<?php $db= DB::table('states_table')->get(); ?>
<select class="form-control input-md" name="state">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the state</option>
    <?php foreach ($db as $data) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data->city; ?>">
        <?php echo $data->city;?>
        </option><?php 
    }?>
</select>
```

Comment: There is no need to submit it you can fill the city drop down from using AJAX

Comment: I would like to keep it as simple as possible, I have no knowledge in AJAX, is it not possible save the selection when choosen without clicking submit without using it?

Comment: I think if you use AJAX that will be more simple than submit,suppose user change select box frequently or once choose wrong state then what will you save each data in DB.

Comment: If you do not want to use Ajax rigidly , you may preceed with iframe. Set form target to iframe and hide that iframe .. now submit your form on dropdown changes to save data ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use ajax :

```
    $('#form').on('change','select[name="state"]', function() {
    var province = $('select[name=state]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: './get_city.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {"state": state},
        success: function (data) {
            $('select[name=city]').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

and in the get_city.php connect to db , get the cities and return them on  tags

Answer (score 0):

`$('#state_field_id').click(function(){
var       state=document.getElementById('state_field_name').options[document.getElementById('state_field_name').selectedIndex].text;
});`

you will get selected value